# Mysql index didnt work, query "where (x, y) in ("

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have composite index for example `INDEX name (x,y)`. Where x and y - integer. Why it don't work with the next query:

```
select * from t
where (x, y) in ((1, 1), (2, 2))
```

Result of Explain: using where, file sort

Answer (score 0):

Depends what version of MySQL you use. Optimizing range comparisons for row constructors like the example you show was implemented in MySQL 5.7.

In MySQL 5.6 or earlier versions, this query would produce a result, but could not use an index to improve performance. It would do a table-scan.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html#row-constructor-range-optimization

---

Re your comment confirming that you're using MySQL 5.6:

The workaround for MySQL 5.6 to make sure it uses the index:

```
select * from t where x=1 and y=1
union all
select * from t where x=2 and y=2
```

You'll need an additional union for each element in your `IN()` list.

This might be a good justification to upgrade to MySQL 5.7. For what it's worth, MySQL 5.7 has been GA since 2015-10-21 (27 months ago), and it has had 11 subsequent GA releases since then. It's pretty stable and reliable now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your query from `where (x, y) in ((i1, j1), (i2, j2),(i3,j3),....` to `where x in (i1,i2,i3....) and y in (j1,j2,j3,....)` It often works  in mysql 5.6, and index uses. But the count of elements "i" must be the same as "j".  It will get the same result as `x=i1 and y=j1 union all` , but not for all queries. And i1,j1,i2,j2,i3,j3...  must be ordered. Try this.

Comment: Your solution will match a row where x=1 and y=2, but that row should not match according to the OP's query.

Comment: This workaround work for me, but i migrated to Mysql 5.7. it's better solution.

Comment: Bill Karwin  No, you are a little wrong. It will match row where x=1 y=1.

Comment: @Mik - But yours will _erroneously_ match `x=1 AND y=2`.  So, I consider it to be an invalid Answer.